# Last column in a specific row with the error "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title says I want to get the last column in a specific row. I tried that with my function `lastColumnForRow(sheet, row)` which is pretty similar to my function `lastRowForColumn(sheet, column)`. However I get an error with `getLastColumn()` in `lastColumnForRow(sheet, row)` and `lastRowForColumn(sheet, column)` is working as intended. Does somebody know a better way or how to fix this problem?

In my sheet there was a value in the last column, so I added a new column without values, but that didn't fix the issue. Also I've tried `getLastColumn()-1` but here's the same problem.

```
function lastRowForColumn(sheet, column){
  // Get the last row with data for the whole sheet.

  // Get all data for the given column

  // Iterate backwards and find first non empty cell

}

function lastColumnForRow(sheet, row){
  // Get the last column with data for the whole sheet.
  var numColu = sheet.getLastColumn();

  // Get all data for the given row
  var data2 = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColu).getValues();

  // Iterate backwards and find first non empty cell
  for(var j = data2.length - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j--){
    if (data[0][j] != null && data[0][j] != ""){
      return j + 1;
    }
  }
}


function Missionen() {
 var gros = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Großaufträge");
  var schab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Schablonen");
  var name = gros.getRange(9, 3).getValue();
  gros.getRange(12, lastColumnForRow(gros, 12)+1).setValue("Auftrag "+name);
}
```

I tried to get the maximum amount of columns in a row and then iterate backwards to find the first non-empty cell. If I try to execute the code there always occurs the issue

> "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. (line 18, file "Code")"

based on the call `getLastColumn()`.

Comment: `numColu` isn't  the problem. `row` is. What's the input value of `row` and is it inside the dimensions of the sheet? What is line 18?

Comment: @TheMaster I use the function `lastColumnForRow(sheet, row)` in function `Missionen()`. As you can see the input is row 12 (it's inside the dimensions). Line 18 is `var numColu = sheet.getLastColumn()`

Comment: My guess is that if you would take the time to create a [mcve] you will probably figure out what the problem is yourself.  Without a [mcve] it's difficult  for us to debug the problem.  But I've been volunteering enough to predict the @TheMaster is probably correct.

Comment: Line 18 is NOT ``var numColu = sheet.getLastColumn()``. Kindly check again. Are you sure Row12 is present in `gros` sheet? Are there any global variables?

Comment: @TheMaster here you can see the line: https://imgur.com/a/B2cZwtk Row 12 is present and there are no global variables. I'll create a minimal reproducible example like Cooper said.

Comment: Ok. Are you sure that the error `The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. (line 18, file "Code")"` is on the same line? Because there is no target range here in this line.

Comment: Hmm I tried this now on a new sheet and this issue no longer exists. There must be a problem with my current sheet. The debugger showed it's line 18.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new sheet, copy the data there and try the code? Sometimes Google Apps Script has a bug where the Spreadsheet script points to a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to get the last column is all rows.

This function generates the data:

```
function makeSomeData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clearContents();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,25,25);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var k=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[0].length-k;j++) {
      vA[i][j]=j+1;
    }
    k++;
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

This function calculates the lengths of each row

```
function findLastColumnInARow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rowA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i].length>0) {
      var row=removeEmptyCellsAtEndOfArray(vA[i]);
      rowA.push(row.length);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(rowA);
  //[25.0, 24.0, 23.0, 22.0, 21.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0, 16.0, 15.0, 14.0, 13.0, 12.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
}
function removeEmptyCellsAtEndOfArray(arr) {
  if(arr) {
    for(var i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
      if(arr[i]=='') {
        arr.splice(i,1);
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I think you can rewrite your function like this:

```
function lastColumnForRow(sheet, row){
  var data=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var rA=removeEmptyCellsAtEndOfArray(data);
  return rA.length;
}
```

Comment: I also tried the function `findLastColumnInARow()` and my function `lastColumnForRow(sheet, row)`. These doesn't update for some reason: If I add some value next to the last column with value in a row with this code and then redo this process, always the same cell will update and not the cell next to it. The function `findLastColumnInARow()` also counts only numbers, which it shouldn't do.

Comment: Nevermind, there was a mistake in my code! Now it's working as intended :) Thanks a lot @all for you help!

Comment: I thought about this a little more last night and I realized that `data.filter` is not a good choice because it does just remove the nulls at the end of the array is removes all of them so if you have empty cells near the beginning of the row they get deleted also.

Comment: yeah I used my function now and it didn't work if I have no input in row like @TheMaster said.

Comment: Don't call the function if row.length==0;